# Who are or were (if ever) the human-jinn hybrid children of shayton?

Tags: jinn, shaitan

[Qur-an 17.64:](http://quran.com/17/64)

> Allah says to shayton "and share in their money and children

[Qur-an 55.56:](http://quran.com/55/56)

> Their beautiful mates were never touched by any human or jinn.

[Qur-an 55.74:](http://quran.com/55/74)

> Whom no man or Jinn before them has touched;

(Translations taken from https://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/quran/

Ayah 64 seems to allude to the fact that shayton the accursed will have hybrid offspring with humans.

This allusion is corroborated by the reassurance that in Janna, female mates will not have been touched (deflowered) by jinns, implying that in this lower life (hayat adDunya) such a thing is possible.

Further, I have an Arabic tafseer book, and the tafseer of this sign (aaya) makes it clear that such a thing is possible.  In fact, according to the book, the mother of Bilqees, Queen of Saba (Sheba) was a jinn.  I could translate the passage if someone really wants me to.

So my question is, who are or were (if ever) the human-jinn hybrid children of shayton?  Any info on how they could be identified?  Any other tafseer anyone's read on the issue?

Comment: Your inquiry could be considered as an interesting question, but I assume you'll reach answers sooner if you make it more limited to be easier for the respondents to respond to it. و من الله توفیق

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to clarify one thing. There is no such thing called Human/Jinn offspring. Humans are made from Clay. Jinn are made from fire. Jinn are capable of inciting ideas and thoughts that provoke us, human race, to commit sins.

To understand the first verse with regards to sharing, we need to go through the whole verse:

> 17:64 And incite [to senselessness] whoever you can among them with your voice and assault them with your horses and foot soldiers and become a partner in their wealth and their children and promise them." But Satan does not promise them except delusion.

**Your horses**: here refer to two kind of categories. Jinn who follow Shaytan "Satin-Iblis" and incite thoughts as he does, or Humans as well who follow his foot steps.

**Your foot soldiers**: here refer to the same two categories except that they don't ride horses.

**become a partner/share in their wealth and their children**: partnership or sharing here is not physical in sexual sense. Rather it's actually means you share them by commanding them to use their wealth in something that doesn't get them benefit. Like spending on the Gods as pagan Arabs used to do before islam or using money in Interest which is forbidden by Islam. Or taking money from people by steeling, robbing or etc... Sharing their children in the same form and manner, like pagan arabs used to sacrifice their children to the Gods (Idols they used to worship), burying females once they are born, convincing children to worship the devil rather than God extra. Please refer to my reference.

> 55:56 In them are women limiting [their] glances, untouched before them by man or jinni.

There is 2 ways of understanding this:

First, we know that Jinn kind are people just like us (Humans). They have the good people and the bad people. The only difference between them and us, they could hear and see us we couldn't. Multiple scholars said that this verse here refers to Men from both kinds (Human/Jinn) who will enter paradise and have spouses from their kind (Human/Jinn). And that's why it's mentioned in that way. The message of Islam came to both Humans and Jinn and the evidence of that, the whole chapter that speaks about them named: Al-Jinn.

Second way of understanding this, it's recommended for husband and wife to say a prayer before coming together to be intimate. Some scholars said if they forgot to say it, they worst of Jinn kind (Shaytan) comes and incite something bad for that fetal that shall be formed in the womb.

I personally, prefer the first understanding.

At the end, that the best we could present and Allah knows best.

References: (unfortunately in arabic)

- http://qurancomplex.gov.sa/Quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?l=arb&t=TABARY&nSora=17&nAya=64#17_64
- http://qurancomplex.gov.sa/Quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?l=arb&t=TABARY&nSora=55&nAya=56#55_56

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed hybrid children of Jinn and Human parents. The Marid and the Sheyaten are the two types that mostly reproduce with humans because they can shape-shift into anything including a human and they are strong enough to maintain the form for long periods of time. These hybrids are born with several mutations most notably double Simian lines on both palms typically with O negative blood and typically with green eyes. In the west they are called Perakee and in the east they are called Zouie. Some are good some are evil but all have intense powers of concentration, premonitions, strong open pineal glands, and often have control over one or more elements. If they inherit too much Jinn genetics they become Black Eyed children and curse any human who allows them entrance into their space.

Comment: any proof for the claims you have made?

Answer (score -4):

You are saying that there is no such thing as human jinn hybrids because men are made from clay and jinn are made from fire! 
What do you do with clay? 
How do you bake clay? 
By using fire!